# How to rebase master into sha using node js

Tags: node.js, git

How can I merge master into a branch using node js? I want to be able to specify a comment on the Git pull-request page, "rebase master", that triggers a webhook that merges master into the branch. I tried using the spawn function in node js to rebase master into a PR. Using GIT enterprise.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: What "pull-request page" are you referring to? Are you using GitHub? GitLab? Something else?

Comment: are you using github api or something like that ? :|